# Highcharts: Using JSON to load xAxis data as 'datetime'?

Tags: php, json, datetime, highcharts

I'm trying to get my xAxis in Highcharts to use the 'datetime' format instead of regular categories, but I'm not sure on how to do this. Please check the following picture to see what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCOb4.png

Output from data.php:

```
[
{"name":"datetime","data":[1439929080000,1439929140000,1439929200000, ...
{"name":"krypTemp","data":[17,17.3,17.2,17.3,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2, ...
{"name":"vindTemp","data":[19,18.9,18.9,18.8,18.8,18.7,18.7,18.7,18.7, ...
{"name":"uteTemp","data":[15,15.5,15.5,15.4,15.4,15.4,15.3,15.4,15.3, ...
{"name":"krypFukt","data":[59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59, ...
{"name":"vindFukt","data":[49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50, ...
]
```

And current configuration for my html page:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'spline'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            series: []
        }
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            options.series[2] = json[3];
            options.series[3] = json[4];
            options.series[4] = json[5];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

I know that datetime and categories conflict with eachother but not how I am supposed to rewrite this "options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];" to fit/be displayed as 'datetime'.

Any help on this would be much appreciated as it is the last step towards my goal :).

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have a datetime type of axis, you cannot use categories, because this is different type.

Replace this line:

```
options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
```

with

```
options.xAxis.tickPositions = json[0]['data'];
```

In case when labels are printed as numbers, you can use a [labels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and use [Highcharts.datetime](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat) inside.